# Angular Node - send token to server upon opening new browser window

Tags: angularjs, node.js, token, passport.js, jwt

The question is pretty self-explanatory: I have a token stored on my browser. When I log in, the server-side authentication middleware uses Passport to authenticate me. However, when I close and re-open my browser window the token is still there but Passport doesn't know who I am.

**How can I retrieve the token from the client side to the server side?**

Below is my code.

```
app.get('/main', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
    // thingToSend gets sent the first time, I will modify it
    // later so it doesn't resend token if token exists
    var thingToSend = {
        token: createSendToken(req.user, config.secret),
        id: req.user._id,
        username: req.user.username,
        authorization: req.user.authorization
    };      
    res.render('main.ejs', thingToSend);
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login_page');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to my problem was to make a request interceptor which I injected in app.config. The request interceptor collects the token, and anytime after my initial session the request interceptor attaches the token to the request header:

```
app.factory('httpInterceptor', function($q, $store, $window) {
return {
    request: function (config){
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        if($store.get('token')){
            var token = config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $store.get('token');
        }
        return config;
    },
    responseError: function(response){
        if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
            $window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/login";
        }
        return $q.reject(response);
    }
};
});
```

It then uses function `ensureAuthentication()` to check either  a) `Passport.authentication` upon initial login, or b) checks token authentication anytime after that in a custom function `checkAuthentication()`.

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    } else {
        var x = checkAuthentication(req, res, next);
        if (x === true) {
            return next();
        } else {
            res.redirect('/login_Page');
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone interested in seeing `checkAuthentication()` or my progress in troubleshooting a related issue regarding JSON web tokens: [JWT not decoding "JWT malformed" - Node Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35375215/jwt-not-decoding-jwt-malformed-node-angular)

Answer (score 1):

You should add an request interceptor to your angular app and attach your auth token along with every request you send to the server.

Read more about request interceptors here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Figured that out a couple hours back and I am working on a function. I will post the function when I figure out a fix, if you are interested in looking at it.